# What is System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.GetCallableMethod in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using [dottrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) to find and fix performance bottlenecks of our asp.net core web application. In profiling results, I'm seeing a method named 
`System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.GetCallableMethod` and I can't understated what is this. 
[image]

I just find out the problem is in Razor render view section.

[image: All time consuming paths will end up to <code>System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.GetCallableMethod</code>]
All time consuming paths will end up to `System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.GetCallableMethod`

So my question is:

1. What is `System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.GetCallableMethod` and why it is time consuming?
2. How I can fix this performance bottleneck? I can't use view caching easily because of `ViewData` is different every time.

Comment: when you say "I can't use view caching easily because of some small parts of each view is different every time.", do you mean contents of the view or markup of the view? If this is actually a bottleneck, it means the view gets re-compiled every time and this is a bit strange.

Comment: Content is not changing. `ViewData` used in view is different every time. For example `@ViewData["DisplayId"]` is different every time.

Comment: Are you profiling stable state after a warm up or just the very first run of the page? From the code (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6a6c8ca5448dd414a7b67e26ed168d29bc5930d6/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/RazorPageActivator.cs#L48) it looks like `CreateViewActivationInfo` should not be called each time page is rendered. You might also consider using https://blog.rsuter.com/precompile-asp-net-mvc-razor-views-in-release-mode-to-find-errors-at-compile-time/

Comment: This profile result is for after warm up and server is under heavy load which it was unable to handle more requests